# My purpose is to be able to check and change the color of blue

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML: I want to be able to use the input checkbox to change the color of the p-tag Blue.
But somehow I'm not able to do.

```
<nav>
<input type="checkbox" id="filter_lz" name="filter" value="Lange Zwaarden">
</nav>

<article>
  <section class="container_lz" id="check1">
    <p>Blue</p>
  </section>
  <section class="container_mz" id="check2">
    <p>Black</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

CSS: I can't find the reason why this isn't working.

```
#filter_lz:checked ~ article #check1 {
  color: red;
}

.container_lz, .container_mz{
  color: blue;
  display: block
}
```

Comment: This is not how `~` selector works... this is why it does not work. with your html structure you need to use js

Comment: `~` is the general sibling combinator and your `article` isn't a sibling of `#filter_lz`

Answer (score 1):

Because your input is not sibling with article, try this:

```css
#filter_lz:checked ~ article #check1 {
  color: red;
}

.container_lz, .container_mz{
  color: blue;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="filter_lz" name="filter" value="Lange Zwaarden">

<article>
  <section class="container_lz" id="check1">
    <p>Blue</p>
  </section>
  <section class="container_mz" id="check2">
    <p>Black</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the DOM with user action you should use js. Add a function, eventlistener/event  and add your action in the function body.

```js
function clicked(){
  document.getElementById("check1").style.color = "blue";
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" onClick="clicked()" id="filter_lz" name="filter" value="Lange Zwaarden">
</nav>

<article>
  <section class="container_lz" id="check1">
    <p>Blue</p>
  </section>
  <section class="container_mz" id="check2">
    <p>Black</p>
  </section>
</article>
```